# What is the difference between returning an invoked function vs JSX directly?

Tags: reactjs, jsx

What is the difference between

```
const Component = () => {
  const renderLeft = () => {
      return (
        <LeftDiv ..../>
      )
  }
  const renderRight = () => {
      if (something) return null;
      return (
        <RightDiv ..../>
      )
  }
  ...

  return (
    <>
      {renderLeft()}
      {renderRight()}
    </>
  )
}
```

and

```
const Component = () => {

  return (
    <>
      <LeftDiv ..../>
      <CenterDiv ..../>
      {something && <RightDiv ..../>}
    </>
  )
}
```

(besides fewer lines of code)?

For context, I sometimes see code written in method #1 in our codebase (but I prefer #2 but am not too sure how to articulate why one is better besides readability), and I was not sure if there are any performance differences between the two methods.

Comment: In this case #1 is less performant. First of all the renderLeft and renderRight functions will be recreated on every rerender of Component and second of all `renderLeft` is just a function that calls another function, thus resulting in one more function call every render.

Comment: Is there a way to measure the performance difference?

Comment: Short answer: The 2nd approach looks clean and easy to understand.

Answer (score 0):

There is not any big difference between these ways to write code. In fact, the first way has less performance than the second one, because there is more than one declared arrow functions, functions calls, et cetera.

But, considering React ecosystem and ignoring performance level, there is not important difference between these ways.